# Responsive friendly square openstreetmap

Tags: html, css, openstreetmap

I'm using this code to display an openstreetmap. It works great on a desktop display but it's not very responsive friendly. I like to have a square sized map. I'm having some problems to find the right parameters for a responsive hight and width.
How can I set it to a 1:1 ratio?

My demo of the below source code: https://jsfiddle.net/uyn9posg/

```
<link id="cf7-map-field-leaflet-css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />

<script id="cf7-map-field-leaflet-js" src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative">
   <div id="CF7MapFieldDiv" style="height:600px;width:100%"></div>
   <span style="position:absolute;right:0px;bottom:20px;font: 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.698);padding:2px 7px;z-index: 1000;" >
        Marker bei: <span id="CF7MapMarkerAt">none</span>
    </span>
</div>
<script>
var map;
var marker;

function updateMarkerPosition(e) {
    //var markerLatLang = [e.lat.toFixed(6), e.lng.toFixed(6)].join(',');
    var markerLong = e.lng.toFixed(6);
    var markerLat = e.lat.toFixed(6);

    //document.getElementById('CF7MapMarkerAt').innerHTML = markerLatLang;
    document.getElementById('CF7MapMarkerAt').innerHTML = "Lat="+markerLat +", Long="+markerLong;
    var hidd = document.getElementById('CF7MapLocationHidden');
    var hidd2 = document.getElementById('CF7MapLocationHidden_long');
    var hidd3 = document.getElementById('CF7MapLocationHidden_lat');
    var hidd4 = document.getElementById('CF7MapLocationHidden_zoom');
    //var val = [map.getZoom(), markerLatLang].join(';');
    var zoomstufe = map.getZoom();
    //if (!!hidd) { hidd.value = val; }
    if (!!hidd2) { hidd2.value = markerLong; }
    if (!!hidd3) { hidd3.value = markerLat; }
    if (!!hidd4) { hidd4.value = zoomstufe; }

}

function onMarkerDrag(e) {
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getLatLng());
}
function onMapClick(e) {
map.removeLayer(initMarker);
    if (marker === undefined) {
        var markerIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4.4/images/marker-icon.png',
            shadowUrl: 'http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4.4/images/marker-shadow.png',
            iconSize: [25, 41],
            shadowSize: [41, 41],
            shadowAnchor: [15, 41]
        });
        marker = L.marker(e.latlng, {
            icon: markerIcon,
            draggable: true
        }).addTo(map);
        marker.on('drag', onMarkerDrag);
    } else {
        marker.setLatLng([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]);
    }

    updateMarkerPosition(e.latlng);
}
 var initMarker = {};
function initmap() {
    // set up the map
    map = new L.Map('CF7MapFieldDiv');
    // create the tile layer with correct attribution
    var mapUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var mapAttrib = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
    var mapTile = new L.TileLayer(mapUrl, {
        minZoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: mapAttrib
    });
    map.addLayer(mapTile);
    // set default view (London)
    //map.setView(new L.LatLng(51.501, -0.105), 8);
map.setView(new L.LatLng(47.77929097015571, 9.609822830498674), 9);

    initMarker = L.marker([47.77929097015571, 9.609822830498674], {
            iconUrl: 'http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4.4/images/marker-icon.png',
            shadowUrl: 'http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4.4/images/marker-shadow.png',
            iconSize: [25, 41],
            shadowSize: [41, 41],
            shadowAnchor: [15, 41],         draggable: true
    }).addTo(this.map);

    // add events
    map.on('click', onMapClick);

}
initmap();
</script>
```

Comment: I like using 100vw (100% of viewport width) as my height and width - assuming the phone is in vertical position (haven't actually seen anyone use it horizontally in years but hey ho)

Answer (score 0):

### Constraining to the Smallest Viewport Dimension

Not sure if this would be an alright way of doing for your use case. But I usually like to  take the smaller (minimum) of the viewport height  viewport width, `min(100vh,100vw)` and use that to set the `height` and `width` of the element I'm trying to keep a square 1:1 aspect ratio. This will also work for other fractions of viewport height and width. Effectively, this will contain the square to the smallest dimension. Press the blue <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd> button below to see the results and test the responsiveness using the full page link:

### Minimal Example:

```css
.Rectangle {
  --Dimensions: min(80vh, 80vw);
  height: var(--Dimensions);
  width: var(--Dimensions);

  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - var(--Dimensions)/2);
  left: calc(50% - var(--Dimensions)/2);

  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="Rectangle"></div>
```

---

### Map Implementation:

```html
<link id="cf7-map-field-leaflet-css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />

<script id="cf7-map-field-leaflet-js" src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div style="position:relative">
   <div id="CF7MapFieldDiv" style="height:min(100vh,100vw); width:min(100vh,100vw); left: calc(50% - min(100vh,100vw)/2)"></div>
   <span style="position:absolute;right:0px;bottom:20px;font: 12px Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.698);padding:2px 7px;z-index: 1000;" >
        Marker bei: <span id="CF7MapMarkerAt">none</span>
    </span>
</div>
<script>
var map;
var marker;

function updateMarkerPosition(e) {
    //var markerLatLang = [e.lat.toFixed(6), e.lng.toFixed(6)].join(',');
    var markerLong = e.lng.toFixed(6);
    var markerLat = e.lat.toFixed(6);

    //document.getElementById('CF7MapMarkerAt').innerHTML = markerLatLang;
    document.getElementById('CF7MapMarkerAt').innerHTML = "Lat="+markerLat +", Long="+markerLong;
    var hidd = document.getElementById('CF7MapLocationHidden');
    var hidd2 = document.getElementById('CF7MapLocationHidden_long');
    var hidd3 = document.getElementById('CF7MapLocationHidden_lat');
    var hidd4 = document.getElementById('CF7MapLocationHidden_zoom');
    //var val = [map.getZoom(), markerLatLang].join(';');
    var zoomstufe = map.getZoom();
    //if (!!hidd) { hidd.value = val; }
    if (!!hidd2) { hidd2.value = markerLong; }
    if (!!hidd3) { hidd3.value = markerLat; }
    if (!!hidd4) { hidd4.value = zoomstufe; }

}

function onMarkerDrag(e) {
    updateMarkerPosition(marker.getLatLng());
}
function onMapClick(e) {
map.removeLayer(initMarker);
    if (marker === undefined) {
        var markerIcon = L.icon({
            iconUrl: 'http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4.4/images/marker-icon.png',
            shadowUrl: 'http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4.4/images/marker-shadow.png',
            iconSize: [25, 41],
            shadowSize: [41, 41],
            shadowAnchor: [15, 41]
        });
        marker = L.marker(e.latlng, {
            icon: markerIcon,
            draggable: true
        }).addTo(map);
        marker.on('drag', onMarkerDrag);
    } else {
        marker.setLatLng([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng]);
    }

    updateMarkerPosition(e.latlng);
}
 var initMarker = {};
function initmap() {
    // set up the map
    map = new L.Map('CF7MapFieldDiv');
    // create the tile layer with correct attribution
    var mapUrl = 'https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var mapAttrib = '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors';
    var mapTile = new L.TileLayer(mapUrl, {
        minZoom: 2,
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: mapAttrib
    });
    map.addLayer(mapTile);
    // set default view (London)
    //map.setView(new L.LatLng(51.501, -0.105), 8);
map.setView(new L.LatLng(47.77929097015571, 9.609822830498674), 9);

    initMarker = L.marker([47.77929097015571, 9.609822830498674], {
            iconUrl: 'http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4.4/images/marker-icon.png',
            shadowUrl: 'http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.4.4/images/marker-shadow.png',
            iconSize: [25, 41],
            shadowSize: [41, 41],
            shadowAnchor: [15, 41],         draggable: true
    }).addTo(this.map);

    // add events
    map.on('click', onMapClick);

}
initmap();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks,That looks like a good solution and it's working on my desktop but my iphone displays just a line of the map. There seems to be an issue with the hight not showing up

Comment: That's quite odd. This method has never failed me on any mobile browsers for sizing elements. Maybe test this method using a simple div to see if it has to do with the way the map is being handled.

Comment: I tested only the code above in a seperate html file. In eg Ubuntu and firefox it also doesn't show the map

Comment: Very interesting, it works for me on Firefox, Chrome and Safari on MacOS and Windows. Hmm, I would be surprised if this has something to do with Linux. I'll look more into it.

Comment: In the mean time try to get the minimal example I added working in as HTML/CSS files. I would probably separate the single HTML file into HTML/CSS/JS files it might help in figuring out what's the issue.

Comment: Also include all the `<html>` and header tags.